# How to draw cross section of this plan by hand?

Tags: interior

[image]

Please tell how to draw cross section of this plan draw and tell roughly.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is likely off-topic (drawing product recommendations), and hard to understand to boot.

Comment: I do not see a product request just a how to do it by hand , as most permits I deliver to the county require a sketch, I don’t see an issue.

Comment: From your question,  What is a cross Section?  What are you asking for with this part, and we need clarification on the last part.  "and tell roughly",  Tell roughly "what"?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Programmer66 I'm sure that they mean a section view, and probably at the two black arrows

Comment: Remember, it’s just a “slice” through the house. Pretend you slice through the house and take part away. Then “look” into the remaining part and draw what is left at the slice...you don’t have to show what is beyond the slice.

Answer (score 2):

Get some engineering graph paper and a construction stencil , this is how I still lay out jobs for a permit, they can be done without the stencils but reviewers have fewer questions. Questions delay the permits.

Comment: STENCIL OR TEMPLATE??+

Comment: I guess to me they are the same but that may help others understand.

Comment: That's what LEGO'S are for...lol  stay safe.